# Fragment addtobackstack crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am a beginner to android and java, and currently i am working on a project that use two fragments and two buttons in my main activity and i have implemented OnClickListener to invoke those buttons. On clicking the button it will display corresponding fragment, i have also used `addtobackstack();` method to stop them from exiting the app, Problem is when i click back button, fragment is destroyed and moved to main activity, and when i click the button to start the same fragment again the app crashes..
code in main Activity,

```
public class Login_Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Login login = new Login();
    Register register = new Register();
    FragmentManager fmanager = getFragmentManager();

    ImageButton LoginB, RegisterB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_register);
        LoginB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        RegisterB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Reg_button);
        LoginB.setOnClickListener(this);
        RegisterB.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fmanager.beginTransaction();
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login_button:

            transaction.add(R.id.Parent, login, "Loginf");
            transaction.addToBackStack("Login");

            transaction.commit();

            break;
        case R.id.Reg_button:

            transaction.add(R.id.Parent, register, "registerf");
            transaction.addToBackStack("registerf");
            transaction.commit();
            break;
        default:

            break;
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Fragment names are Login and Register, its code(Only Login fragments):

```
    public class Login extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View login=inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return login;
    }

}
```

Logcat o/p:

```
08-21 12:14:27.517: D/OpenGLRenderer(10662): Enabling debug mode 0
08-21 12:14:31.860: D/AndroidRuntime(10662): Shutting down VM
08-21 12:14:31.860: W/dalvikvm(10662): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41674d40)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662): Process: com.example.apeonomy, PID: 10662
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class fragment
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at com.digiapes.apeonomy.Login.onCreateView(Login.java:17)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #74: Duplicate id 0x7f040026, tag null, or parent id 0x7f040020 with another fragment for com.digiapes.apeonomy.Face_Goog
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4808)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662):    ... 20 more
08-21 12:14:33.963: I/Process(10662): Sending signal. PID: 10662 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you add some stacktrace? and just try after changing View login=inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false); to View login=inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null);

Comment: i tried as you mentioned, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Harsha post login.xml

Comment: @Harsha Nope thats definitely what I told

Comment: I investigated my login.xml and i found that i had included fragment within a fragment layout which was causing an error.

Comment: thanks for your time and help which helped me notice problem within my code..

Answer (score 0):

can you try using :

```
transaction.replace(R.id.Parent, new Login());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

and

```
transaction.add(R.id.Parent, new Register());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

As your stacktrace clearly indicates your problem lies with the inflation of your layout:

```
08-21 12:14:31.868: E/AndroidRuntime(10662): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class fragment
```

So I guess this is the source of your problem :

```
View login=inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
```

First try :

```
View login=inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null, false);
```

And sometimes the source of the error could be the inflater (I recall this was a common bug) so try to get a fresh inflater yourself:

either :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null, false);
```

or `return View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.login)`;